# ERROR: syntax error at or near "timestamp" when adding column

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to add a column to a table and the following is my command:

```
alter table history add column start type timestamp;
```

I get the following error:

```
syntax error at or near "timestamp"
```

How is this command incorrect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the word `type`, it should be:

```
alter table history add column start timestamp
```

Also, `start` is a non-reserved keyword in PG (but reserved in the SQL99 standard) and as such might not be a good column name.